# Python - 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, recursão

Olá, estou a criar um conversor de caracteres para o seu código em ascii através de uma função recursiva em Python. No entanto estou com um problema "'int' object is not iterable".

O meu código é este:

```
def cod(n):
for i in n:
    i = str(i)    
    if len(n) == 1:
        ascii = ord(i)
        return ascii
    else:
        ascii = ord(i) + cod(ord(i))
        return ascii
```

o erro que retorna é o seguinte:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 8, in codifica
  File "python", line 2, in codifica
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Basicamente estou a recorrer ao `ord()` para obter o número do caracter em ASCII. Quando chamo apenas um caracter tudo corre bem. Se tentar passar mais do que um começam os problemas. 
O problema aparentemente é a variável `i` estar a ser tratada como inteiro mas supostamente eu converto em string ao fazer `i = str(i)`

O que pretendo é que ao executar a função `cod('ola')` ela retorne `11110897` que corresponde à conversão de cada um dos caracteres para ASCII.

Alguém me pode ajudar a perceber onde estou a falhar?

Comment: Só uma dúvida: o retorno dessa função é pra ser uma string ou um número? Respondi assumindo que seja uma string (pois caso contrário, uma chamada `cod("anticonstitucionalissimamente")` ia dar *overflow*...), mas se for algo diferente por favor especificar. Inclusive na sua linha `ascii = ord(i) + cod(ord(i))` você está somando números, o que faria `111 + 108 = 219` e não `111108`.

Comment: Realmente essa soma não fazia sentido nenhum... mas como ainda não tinha sequer conseguido converter dois caracteres não dei conta. Erro de principiante.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seu problema está aqui:

```
cod(ord(i))
```

Você está chamando a função `cod` recursivamente passando o resultado de `ord` - e portanto um inteiro - como argumento. Mas como a primeira coisa que `cod` faz é iterar sobre o argumento:

```
for i in n: # n na segunda chamada é o resultado de ord(i)
```

Então ele reclama que não pode iterar sobre um inteiro.

Como você está usando um `for`, imagino que sua intenção não era criar um código recursivo. Nesse caso, crie uma string "resultado" e vá jogando os valores encontrados nela, para no final retorná-la (isso inclusive evita esse `if` onde você testa se o tamanho da string é `1` ou não):

```
def cod(n):
    resultado = ""
    for i in n:
        # i já é uma string, não precisa fazer i = str(i)
        ascii = ord(i)
        resultado += str(ascii) # ascii é um número, então precisa fazer str(ascii)
    return resultado
```

Uma solução recursiva, por outro lado, não precisaria de um `for`. Basta verificar se a string está vazia ou não, e se não estiver, aplicar o `ord` ao seu primeiro caractere e concatenar com o resultado da aplicação de `cod` ao seu sufixo:

```
def cod(n):
    return "" if n == "" else str(ord(n[0])) + cod(n[1:])
```

Comment: É mesmo isso! :) não ia chegar lá, tentei todo o tipo de coisas, incluindo iterar sobre listas mas aí o 'ord()' não funcionava. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Já agora, há alguma forma de conseguir fazer isso usando uma função recursiva?

Comment: @MarcosLopes Sim, veja a resposta editada.

Answer (score 0):

Estou assumindo que o o erra que esta dando é no primeiro loop do FOR, onde ele nao executa não itera a variável i até chegar ao n.

A melhor maneira de resolver isso é convertendo a condição para range e ficaria dessa forma:

```
def cod(n):
for i in range(len(n)):
    i = str(i)    
    if len(n) == 1:
        ascii = ord(i)
        return ascii
    else:
        ascii = ord(i) + cod(ord(i))
        return ascii
```

Caso queira usar n como numero inteiro no futuro, use

```
for i in range (1, n) :
```