# Ajuda Usando Compreensão de Lista/Dicionário

Tags: python-3.x, lista, dicionário

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte [módulo](https://gist.github.com/Godrigos/c2eb7c030b03f7c1e019cd5c4cb5c22d) (não quis colocar todo o código aqui) em Python >= 3.6.  Ele já é funcional no estado atual, ainda que não trate todos os erros possíveis. Mas quero, para praticar, alterar algumas coisas. Não sou profissional de programação, na verdade sou biólogo, rsrs. Mas uso bastante Python e principalmente R em pesquisa. Logo peço desculpas se o código não é o mais eficiente e limpo possível.

O módulo renomeia arquivos de vídeos que estão com seus números absolutos dos episódios (25) ao invés do padrão por temporada (S02E03).
Basicamente, ele usa o pacote *pymediainfo* para detectar vídeos em uma pasta e então usa o pacote *tvdb_api* para identificar a série e importar informações sobre a mesma. Essas informações serão usadas no processo de alteração do nome do arquivo com número de episódio absoluto para o padrão Temporada/Episódio.

Eu venho tentando substituir os laços for para criação das listas inicias por compreensão de lista. Consegui para duas das listas (**season** e **episodes**), mas a terceira (**absoluteNumbers**) eu tentei de muitas maneiras e não consigui.

Basicamente eu quero transformar o seguintes laços for em list ou dict comprehension:

```
for key in show:
    for value in show[key]:
        absoluteNumbers.append(show[key][value]['absoluteNumber'])
```

De forma semelhante ao feito com as outras duas listas:

```
seasons = [key for key in show for value in show[key]]
episodes = [value for key in show for value in show[key]]
```

Minha tentativa inicial foi:

```
[absNum for k in show for v in show[k] for absNum in show[k][v]['absoluteNumber']]
```

Mas o resultado não é o esperado, algo como uma lista contendo a sequência de números absolutos dos episódio da série. Por exemplo, se tivemos duas temporadas de 10 episódio a lista teria os números de 1 a 20. O que obtenho é um erro:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Já tentou debugar e ver o que esta saindo, tipo imprimir cada valor desse `for`? porque esse erro ocorre quando você tenta inteirar um inteiro tipo, fazer um `for` com o numeral 1, ai qualquer linguagem fica meio perdida, por que você só pode inteirar se for uma lista,arry dics . nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102931/python-int-object-is-not-iterable) pode te ajudar entender melhor.

Comment: Então, eu fiz um debug e erro é esse mesmo, na minha versão ele tenta iterar um tipo None, o problema é que não consigo contornar isso, a lógica desse list comprehension está me escapando bonito.

`'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: tu pode me passar um exemplo de nome de arquivo? Ver se eu testo aqui e te dou uma reposta melhor

Comment: Cara, eu rodei aqui e coloque o nome do arquivo de 'Leverage' uma serie. Ai ve que tem alguns `absolutenumber` que esta como `None`. O que tu pode fazer para contornar isso é um contador, já que ele passa por todas as temporadas e cada vez que ele passa é um novo episódio ai vai somando a cada passada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analisando o [código do módulo `tvdb_api`](https://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/f6ae3c98e3ff701e6c6ba8338d5ac37fc7ad5a00/tvdb_api.py) que você está usando, a classe [`Show`](https://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/f6ae3c98e3ff701e6c6ba8338d5ac37fc7ad5a00/tvdb_api.py#L288) e [`Season`](https://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/f6ae3c98e3ff701e6c6ba8338d5ac37fc7ad5a00/tvdb_api.py#L407) são filhas de `dict` onde os valores da classe `Show` são temporadas (como visto no [código do método `Show.search()`](https://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/f6ae3c98e3ff701e6c6ba8338d5ac37fc7ad5a00/tvdb_api.py#L399)) e os valores da classe `Season` são épisódios (visto no [código do método `Season.search()`](https://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/f6ae3c98e3ff701e6c6ba8338d5ac37fc7ad5a00/tvdb_api.py#L436)).

Ou seja, o código a seguir itera sobre todos os episódios de todas as temporadas e dá um `print` dos episódios tratando `Show` e `Season` como dicionários:

```
from tvdb_api import Tvdb

api = Tvdb()
serie = api['friends']

for season in serie.values():
    for ep in season.values():
        print(ep)
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-394901-6333-a)</sup>

A saída seria algo como:

```
<Episode 01x01 - 'The One Where Monica Gets A Roommate'>
<Episode 01x02 - 'The One With The Sonogram At The End'>
<Episode 01x03 - 'The One With The Thumb'>
<Episode 01x04 - 'The One With George Stephanopoulos'>
<Episode 01x05 - 'The One With The East German Laundry Detergent'>
<Episode 01x06 - 'The One With The Butt'>
...
...
...
<Episode 10x15 - 'The One Where Estelle Dies'>
<Episode 10x16 - "The One With Rachel's Going Away Party (a.k.a. The One Where Rachel Goes ToParis)">
<Episode 10x17 - 'The Last One (1)'>
<Episode 10x18 - 'The Last One (2)'>
```

---

Para pegar apenas o `absoluteNumber` de cada episódio bastaria tratar o episódio como um `dict` e pegar o valor usando `ep['absoluteNumber']`. Usando *list comprehension* ficaria:

```
from tvdb_api import Tvdb

api = Tvdb()
serie = api['friends']

absoluteNumbers = [episodio['absoluteNumber'] for season in serie.values() 
                                              for episodio in season.values()]

print(absoluteNumbers)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 234, None, None]
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-394901-6333-b)</sup>

---

Você precisa lembra que o TVDB é um banco de dados preenchido por voluntários e muitos dados podem não existir, como os valores `None` mostrados no código acima.

De qualquer maneira, acredito que isso explique como criar uma lista de `absoluteNumbers` dos episódios usando *comprehension*. Basta lembrar que as classes `Show`, `Season` e `Episode` por algum motivo herdam de [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), então você pode iterá-los usando os métodos [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) e [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi a própria API da tvbd não tem as informações dos `absoluteNumber` para todos os episódios, ai por isso retorna `None`. Uma solução seria "criar" o seu próprio `absoluteNumber`, como segue no trexo de código abaixo.

```
absoluteNumber = 0
for key in show:
    for value in show[key]:
        absoluteNumber+=1
        absoluteNumbers.append(absoluteNumber)
```